# Using fancybox - how can I tell if an HTTP request is AJAX or not?

Tags: ajax, zend-framework

I'm using  [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/) plugin to load a page and execute some code. The problem is that at times theres always the chance that someone would click on a link thats meant to be opened in a fancybox window before the page loads completely and the fancybox plugin is set up opening the page looking messed up in an complete browser window. Is there a way to tell whether an HTTP request is via ajax or not so I can set up my layouts accordingly.

I'm using the zend framework and have defined two layouts one for pages opened with fancybox and one is the regular page layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In you actions you can use [isXmlHttpRequest()](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.request.html#zend.controller.request.http.ajax) method to detect ajax request. For example, you could do:

```
public function onlyajaxAction() {

    if ($this->getRequest()->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        // handel ajax request.           
    } else {
        // if not an ajax request, e.g. throw an exception or whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: But only if `X-Requested-With` header is set properly AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the `X-Requested-With` header, which is set to `XMLHttpRequest` by many Javascript libraries.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a same action in different context to provide the according result, you may use the [`contextSwitcher()` action helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.contextswitch) (or `ajaxContext()`)

```
<?php
class YourController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function init ()
    {
        $ajaxContext = $this->_helper->getHelper('AjaxContext');
        $ajaxContext->addActionContext('do-something', 'json')
            ->initContext();
    }

    public function doSomethingAction ()
    {
        // some logic here
        $this->view->data = $data;
    }
}
```

Use the `?format=json` parameter to switch context, in case of JSON ZF will take care to convert `$this->view->data` to JSON for you, it will also disable layout, etc.